# Can't include OpenCV functions in Matlab in Linux

Tags: linux, matlab, opencv, mex

I have a .cpp that I'm trying to mex using MATLAB R2011a in Ubuntu 14.04. The file uses some OpenCV functions and imports the correponding library:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
```

I'm mexing using the following command in Matlab:

```
mex -I/usr/local/include FaceDetect.cpp
```

As the opencv libraries are installed in /usr/local/include/opencv. The crash result is as follows:

```
Warning: You are using gcc version "4.8.2-19ubuntu1)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.3.4".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

FaceDetect.o: In function `mexFunction':
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `cvLoad'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `cvCreateMemStorage'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `cvHaarDetectObjects'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `cvGetSeqElem'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `cvClearMemStorage'
FaceDetect.cpp:(.text+0x39f): undefined reference to `cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

     mex: link of ' "FaceDetect.mexa64"' failed.

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully
```

I have tried compiling with -L and -lcv and it still crashes. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: all your errors are related to outdated 2009 c-api functionality. i.e, -lcv won't exist anymore, you want -lopencv_core, -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect (to name the usual suspects). and honestly, the contents of your cpp file might be only good for the garbage bin, too.

Comment: Use [mexopencv](http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/mexopencv/).

Comment: use, whatever has cv::Mat in it. if you see IplImage in there , move on..

Comment: what berak said :) To be exact, those errors are not crashes but *linking* errors. You want to link against the OpenCV shared libraries, so specify the usual: `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core ...`. Also if you have a choice, do try `mexopencv`

Comment: Yes, it's almost not worth the effort to solve this.  Also, it's not hard to use recent versions of OpenCV directly (not matopencv).  Just download 2.4.10 binaries and you're off.  Just link each modules' lib.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox now includes a [support package for OpenCV interface](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-system-toolbox-opencv-interface). It includes a library of conversion routines between MATLAB and OpenCV data types, and an easy way to compile mex functions, which use OpenCV.